# Pause Menu doesn't work - UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've a got a weird problem with my pause menu.
When I press ESC, it' opening my menu and stop the "game" except characters.
I'm using `Time.TimeScale = 0f;`.
I've seen that's a problem with the TimeScale that affect everything "in the game" and if it's desn't work on my characters, that's because they're not in the same TimeScale.

I'm using UNITY 3D 5.6.0 with Visual Studio 2017.

My Code :

```
public static bool pause = false;
public GameObject pauseMenu;

void Update () {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        if(pause)
        {
            Continuer();
        }
        else
        {
            Pause();
        }
    }
}

public void Continuer()
{
    pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    pause = false;
}
public void Pause()
{
    pauseMenu.SetActive(true);
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
    pause = true;
}
```

Does anyone know how to pause the entire game ?

Comment: I've removed your `visual-studio` tag for you. From the `visual-studio` [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio/info): "Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality. DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio. Consider tagging the exact technology area your question links to and also tagging a more specific version of Visual Studio. Please mention your exact VS version, edition, and update level in your question."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Update()` and `OnGUI()` are time-scale independent, so they are not affected by setting `Time.timeScale` to `0`. Only `FixedUpdate()` is affected from it.

As the [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) says:

> When timeScale is set to zero the game is basically paused **if all
>   your functions are frame rate independent**. *(emphasis by me)*

You should use some logic behind your `Update()` calls, like these:

1) Let movements be time-scale dependent. If your characters move with translation, do this:

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);
```

2) Apply `Update()` logic only if the game is not paused:

```
void Update(){
     if (Time.timeScale == 0)
         return;
     //...
 }
```

or

```
void Update(){
     if (pause)
         return;
     //...
 }
```